# overflow leaving a lot of white space

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am having a problem with overflow in CSS as it is now leaving a huge area of white space bellow the table.

### the problem:

so say the window is 500px high and I set the height of the `tbody` to 100px with the overflow set to auto. And the html within the `tbody` is 1000px high.

Why will the browser scroll to 1000px not 100px(500px) ?

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6J3X/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<table class="height">
    <tbody class="height">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And Here is my CSS:

```
tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}


thead > tr, tbody{
    display:block;}
```

#### Simple way to look at it.

I only should have one scroll bar. Not this extra one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you enclose it in a div container, and do the same sort of overflow? I'm not sure I would be applying all that to the tbody, unless there was a specific need.

http://jsfiddle.net/bS4pL/

```
.fixedHeight {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}


<div class="fixedHeight">
    <table>
        <tbody class="height">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>a</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **display:block** to your table class. Right now it's **display:table** by default, which behaves differently then regular div blocks.

I would suggest putting the table into a div rather then the body for better control with the css styling as well :)